# Type cannot hold a variable of its own Type - AppGameKit/BASIC

Tags: basic, xmlnode

**Background:** Im attempting to create an XML parser for AppGameKit using tier 1 (the engines own version of BASIC).

**The problem:** The tier 1 language has "Types" (similar to C structs), they contain no functions and cannot hold a variable of the same "Type"

**Example**

```
TYPE XMLNode
  name as String
  value as String
  children as XMLNode[]
  parent as XMLNode
  attributes as String[]
ENDTYPE
```

Is not valid because **XMLNode** cannot have a variable of type **XMLNode**.

**Question:**

Is there a known way around a language that is structured/limited like this that would allow the same result?

Comment: There isn't a way around this in a BASIC dialect like Tier 1. C++ (Tier 2) could do it since it has pointers (and pointers to a type are allowed to be nested), though all marshaling and unmarshaling would need to be done in C++ since Tier 1 clearly can't support arbitrary nesting of types. What is the reason you're trying to roll an XML parser though? Maybe there's an alternative solution? Maybe one even already exists?